# Sage notebook not opening

Tags: sage

I installed the sagemath software on an ubuntu machine and nothing executes. I type

```
sage: notebook()
NameError: name 'notebook' is not defined


sage: 2+3
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)

/home/myusername/Downloads/sage-4.7-linux-32bit-ubuntu_10.04_lts-i686-Linux/local/bin/<ipython console> in <module>()

NameError: name 'Integer' is not defined
```

On opening sage I get the following message

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------
| Sage Version 4.7, Release Date: 2011-05-23                         |
| Type notebook() for the GUI, and license() for information.        |
----------------------------------------------------------------------
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)

/home/myusername/Downloads/sage-4.7-linux-32bit-ubuntu_10.04_lts-i686-Linux/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/IPython/ipmaker.pyc in force_import(modname)
     64         reload(sys.modules[modname])
     65     else:
---> 66         __import__(modname)
     67 
     68 

/home/myusername/Downloads/sage-4.7-linux-32bit-ubuntu_10.04_lts-i686-Linux/local/bin/ipy_profile_sage.py in <module>()
      5     preparser(True)
      6 
----> 7     import sage.all_cmdline
      8     sage.all_cmdline._init_cmdline(globals())
      9 

/home/myusername/Downloads/sage-4.7-linux-32bit-ubuntu_10.04_lts-i686-Linux/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/sage/all_cmdline.py in <module>()
     12 try:
     13 
---> 14     from sage.all import *
     15     from sage.calculus.predefined import x
     16     preparser(on=True)

/home/myusername/Downloads/sage-4.7-linux-32bit-ubuntu_10.04_lts-i686-Linux/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/sage/all.py in <module>()
     89 from sage.algebras.all   import *
     90 from sage.modular.all    import *
---> 91 from sage.schemes.all    import *
     92 from sage.graphs.all     import *
     93 from sage.groups.all     import *

/home/myusername/Downloads/sage-4.7-linux-32bit-ubuntu_10.04_lts-i686-Linux/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/sage/schemes/all.py in <module>()
     23 from jacobians.all import *
     24 
---> 25 from hyperelliptic_curves.all import *
     26 
     27 from plane_curves.all import *

/home/myusername/Downloads/sage-4.7-linux-32bit-ubuntu_10.04_lts-i686-Linux/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/sage/schemes/hyperelliptic_curves/all.py in <module>()
----> 1 
      2 
      3 from constructor import HyperellipticCurve
      4 from hyperelliptic_generic import is_HyperellipticCurve
      5 from kummer_surface import KummerSurface
      6 from invariants import (igusa_clebsch_invariants,
      7                         absolute_igusa_invariants_kohel,

/home/myusername/Downloads/sage-4.7-linux-32bit-ubuntu_10.04_lts-i686-Linux/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/sage/schemes/hyperelliptic_curves/constructor.py in <module>()
      9 #*****************************************************************************

     10 
---> 11 from sage.schemes.generic.all import ProjectiveSpace
     12 
     13 from hyperelliptic_generic import HyperellipticCurve_generic

/home/myusername/Downloads/sage-4.7-linux-32bit-ubuntu_10.04_lts-i686-Linux/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/sage/schemes/generic/all.py in <module>()
      2 
      3 from spec             import Spec, is_Spec
----> 4 from affine_space     import AffineSpace, is_AffineSpace
      5 from algebraic_scheme import is_AlgebraicScheme
      6 from ambient_space    import is_AmbientSpace

/home/myusername/Downloads/sage-4.7-linux-32bit-ubuntu_10.04_lts-i686-Linux/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/sage/schemes/generic/affine_space.pyc in <module>()
     22 from sage.misc.all import latex
     23 
---> 24 import algebraic_scheme
     25 
     26 import ambient_space

/home/myusername/Downloads/sage-4.7-linux-32bit-ubuntu_10.04_lts-i686-Linux/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/sage/schemes/generic/algebraic_scheme.pyc in <module>()
    141 import affine_space
    142 import projective_space
--> 143 import toric_variety
    144 import morphism
    145 import scheme

/home/myusername/Downloads/sage-4.7-linux-32bit-ubuntu_10.04_lts-i686-Linux/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/sage/schemes/generic/toric_variety.py in <module>()
    234 import sys
    235 
--> 236 from sage.geometry.cone import Cone, is_Cone
    237 from sage.geometry.fan import Fan
    238 from sage.matrix.all import matrix

/home/myusername/Downloads/sage-4.7-linux-32bit-ubuntu_10.04_lts-i686-Linux/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/sage/geometry/cone.py in <module>()
    173 
    174 from sage.combinat.posets.posets import FinitePoset
--> 175 from sage.geometry.lattice_polytope import LatticePolytope
    176 from sage.geometry.polyhedra import Polyhedron, Hasse_diagram_from_incidences
    177 from sage.geometry.toric_lattice import ToricLattice, is_ToricLattice

/home/myusername/Downloads/sage-4.7-linux-32bit-ubuntu_10.04_lts-i686-Linux/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/sage/geometry/lattice_polytope.py in <module>()
    110 from sage.plot.plot import hue
    111 from sage.plot.plot3d.index_face_set import IndexFaceSet
--> 112 from sage.plot.plot3d.all import line3d, point3d
    113 from sage.plot.plot3d.shapes2 import text3d
    114 from sage.plot.plot3d.tachyon import Tachyon

/home/myusername/Downloads/sage-4.7-linux-32bit-ubuntu_10.04_lts-i686-Linux/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/sage/plot/plot3d/all.py in <module>()
      3 from parametric_plot3d import parametric_plot3d
      4 from plot_field3d      import plot_vector_field3d
----> 5 from implicit_plot3d   import implicit_plot3d
      6 from list_plot3d       import list_plot3d
      7 from revolution_plot3d import revolution_plot3d

/home/myusername/Downloads/sage-4.7-linux-32bit-ubuntu_10.04_lts-i686-Linux/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/sage/plot/plot3d/implicit_plot3d.py in <module>()
      3 """
      4 
----> 5 from implicit_surface import ImplicitSurface
      6 
      7 def implicit_plot3d(f, xrange, yrange, zrange, **kwds):

/home/myusername/Downloads/sage-4.7-linux-32bit-ubuntu_10.04_lts-i686-Linux/local/bin/numpy.pxd in init sage.plot.plot3d.implicit_surface (sage/plot/plot3d/implicit_surface.c:29094)()

/home/myusername/Downloads/sage-4.7-linux-32bit-ubuntu_10.04_lts-i686-Linux/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/numpy/__init__.pyc in <module>()
    134         return loader(*packages, **options)
    135 
--> 136     import add_newdocs
    137     __all__ = ['add_newdocs']
    138 

/home/myusername/Downloads/sage-4.7-linux-32bit-ubuntu_10.04_lts-i686-Linux/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/numpy/add_newdocs.py in <module>()
      7 #       core/fromnumeric.py, core/defmatrix.py up-to-date.

      8 
----> 9 from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
     10 
     11 ###############################################################################


/home/myusername/Downloads/sage-4.7-linux-32bit-ubuntu_10.04_lts-i686-Linux/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/numpy/lib/__init__.py in <module>()
     11 
     12 import scimath as emath
---> 13 from polynomial import *
     14 #import convertcode

     15 from utils import *

/home/myusername/Downloads/sage-4.7-linux-32bit-ubuntu_10.04_lts-i686-Linux/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/numpy/lib/polynomial.py in <module>()
     15 from numpy.lib.function_base import trim_zeros, sort_complex
     16 from numpy.lib.type_check import iscomplex, real, imag
---> 17 from numpy.linalg import eigvals, lstsq
     18 
     19 class RankWarning(UserWarning):

/home/myusername/Downloads/sage-4.7-linux-32bit-ubuntu_10.04_lts-i686-Linux/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/numpy/linalg/__init__.py in <module>()
     46 from info import __doc__
     47 
---> 48 from linalg import *
     49 
     50 from numpy.testing import Tester

/home/myusername/Downloads/sage-4.7-linux-32bit-ubuntu_10.04_lts-i686-Linux/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/numpy/linalg/linalg.py in <module>()
     21         isfinite, size, finfo, absolute, log, exp
     22 from numpy.lib import triu
---> 23 from numpy.linalg import lapack_lite
     24 from numpy.matrixlib.defmatrix import matrix_power
     25 from numpy.compat import asbytes

ImportError: libgfortran.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Error importing ipy_profile_sage - perhaps you should run %upgrade?
WARNING: Loading of ipy_profile_sage failed.

sage: notebook()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)

/home/myusername/Downloads/sage-4.7-linux-32bit-ubuntu_10.04_lts-i686-Linux/local/bin/<ipython console> in <module>()

NameError: name 'notebook' is not defined
sage: notebook()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)

/home/myusername/Downloads/sage-4.7-linux-32bit-ubuntu_10.04_lts-i686-Linux/local/bin/<ipython console> in <module>()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the line

```
ImportError: libgfortran.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

is the source of the problem.  That error message seemed familiar, and I thought I'd seen it relatively recently: turns out that I was right, it was on a [sage-support thread.](http://groups.google.com/group/sage-support/browse_thread/thread/dfbb2eb171544cd2).  Try installing gfortran.

On Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install libgfortran3
```

Comment: Do you know how to install gfortran in ubuntu? sudo apt-get install gfortran doesnt work